# Left Join Is Not Doing What I expect

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

Totally confused and I have been working at this for 2 hours

I thought restriction on the left side of the join are honored

On this query I am getting  [docSVsys].[visibility] 1 and <> 1
I thought this would restrict [docSVsys].[visibility] to 1

```
select top 1000 
       [docSVsys].[sID], [docSVsys].[visibility] 
      ,[Table].[sID],[Table].[enumID],[Table].[valueID] 
  from [docSVsys]  with (nolock) 
  left Join [DocMVenum1] as [Table] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVsys].[visibility] in (1)
   and [Table].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID]
   and [Table].[enumID] = '140' 
   and [Table].[valueID] in (1,7)
```

This works

```
select top 1000 
       [docSVsys].[sID], [docSVsys].[visibility] 
      ,[Table].[sID],[Table].[enumID],[Table].[valueID] 
  from [docSVsys]  with (nolock) 
  left Join [DocMVenum1] as [Table] with (nolock) 
    on [Table].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID]
   and [Table].[enumID] = '140' 
   and [Table].[valueID] in (1,7)
 where [docSVsys].[visibility] in (1)
```

I am just having a really off day as I had it in my mind the left side honored the join

Comment: No.

Your restriction will only apply to the join.

You need to put `[docSVsys].[visibility] in (1)` in the `WHERE` to avoid seeing those rows where `[docSVsys].[visibility] <> 1` in the result. All your current condition ensures is that they won't join to a row in `DocMVenum1` so will be preserved as non matching and null extended in those columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith As rookie and as basic as that is if you will put it in an answer I will accept it

Comment: You could use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: I'm on a mobile device hence not posting full answer. Usr's posted one now anyway!

Comment: @TimSchmelter - That depends what the desired semantics are for the other three columns involved in the join.

Comment: Yes I need to find nulls in [Table].[sID] but the way my day is going I will mess that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON Condition
```

is equivalent to

```
 SELECT *
 FROM A
 CROSS JOIN B
 WHERE Condition
UNION ALL
 SELECT A.*, NULL AS B
 FROM A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE Condition)
```

Some rough pseudo-code...

Note, that all rows from A get through. It's just that the columns from `B` can be `NULL` if the join fails for some particular row of `A`.

Put the filter on `docSVsys` into the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOINs **preserve** all rows from the left (first) table, no matter what. The condition in the ON clause is only for matching which rows from the right/second table should be paired with rows from the left/first table.

If you want to exclude some rows from the firs table, use the WHERE clause:

```
select top 1000 
   [docSVsys].[sID], [docSVsys].[visibility] 
  ,[Table].[sID],[Table].[enumID],[Table].[valueID] 
from [docSVsys]  with (nolock) 
left Join [DocMVenum1] as [Table] with (nolock) 
  on [Table].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID]
  and [Table].[enumID] = '140' 
  and [Table].[valueID] in (1,7) 
where [docSVsys].[visibility] in (1)
```

Comment: That is big as day in the documentation and have done this correct for a long time.  Not sure what got into my head today.